# How can I create a custom design to this UIBarButtonItemStyle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

Hi Im trying to set a custom style to this UIBarButton but I can't get it to work, how can this be done?

```
UIBarButtonItem *theatersNav = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"THEATERS" 
style:(UIBarButtonItemStyleDone) target:self action:@selector(theatersNavAction:)];
```

I've managed to get a background pic, but i don't seam to be able to change the font, color and sixe of the text

```
UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-normal"];
UIImage *userImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-highlighted.png"];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:userImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:userImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: What style do you want? What have you attempted?

Comment: change font and color

Comment: in the different stats highlighted, normal

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UIBarButtonItem` and `UIBarItem`?

Comment: YES, But I cant get it to wok

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried. Provide details about what issues you are having with the attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `[UIBarButtonItem appearance]`, the setting applies to all new `UIBarButtonItem` instances that you create. It has no effect on any existing `UIBarButtonItem` instances.

If you want to apply the setting to only a single button, don't use `[UIBarButtonItem appearance]`. Apply the setting directly to the button you wish to style.

If you want to apply the setting to all buttons, use `[UIBarButtonItem appearance]` before you create any buttons.

Assuming you want to style just the one button, you want:

```
UIBarButtonItem *theatersNav = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"THEATERS" style:(UIBarButtonItemStyleDone) target:self action:@selector(theatersNavAction:)];

UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-normal"];
UIImage *userImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-highlighted.png"];

[theatersNav setBackgroundImage:userImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[theatersNav setBackgroundImage:userImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: nice, thanks, how do I do to change the font,color and size on all UIBarButtonItem ?

Comment: Use the `setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` method. FYI - don't forget to update/accept useful answers.

Comment: amazing thanks! can I set all UIBarButtonItem to have the same font or do I have to add the font for every button?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, if you wish to apply a style to all bar buttons, you need to apply the style to `[UIBarButtonItem appearance]`. Just do it before creating any buttons.